# Failed to use fprintf() after a function is used

Tags: c, file-io, printf

When I run parsertest, only one line "hello world" in the `stdout`, and nothing in add1.txt.
But when I delete the line: `char * nospace = delespace(line);`, the stdout display many lines, which is the same as linenumber of add.txt, of "hello world", also the same lines "hello world" in add1.txt.

```
-----------parsettest.c-----------------

#include "Parser.c"
#define MAXLEN 100

int main(void){
    FILE * fp;
    FILE * fp2;
    if((fp = fopen("add.txt", "r")) == NULL){
        printf("Can't open add.txt");
        return 0;
    }
    if((fp2 = fopen("add1.txt", "w+"))== NULL){
        printf("Can't creat add1.txt");
        return 0;
    }


    char * line = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * MAXLEN);

    while(fgets(line, MAXLEN, fp)){
        printf("hello world\n" );
        char * nospace = delespace(line);
        fprintf(fp2, "hello world\n");
    } 
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(fp2);
    return 0;
}


-------------Parser.c------------------------
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
char * delespace(char * line){
    int i;
    for(i = 0; line[i] == ' '; i++)
        ;

    if(line[i] == '\n')
        return NULL;

    char * newline = malloc(sizeof(line) + 1);
    int j = 0;
    for(int i = 0; line[i] != '\0'; i++){
        if(line[i] == ' ')
            continue;

        newline[j++] = line[i];
    }
    newline[j] = '\0';
    printf("%s", newline);
    return newline;
}

--------------add.txt----------------------------
// This file is part of www.nand2tetris.org
// and the book "The Elements of Computing Systems"
// by Nisan and Schocken, MIT Press.
// File name: projects/06/add/Add.asm

// Computes R0 = 2 + 3  (R0 refers to RAM[0])

@2
D=A
@3
D=D+A
@0
M=D
```

Answer (score 1):

In `char * delespace(char * line)` function,

```
char * newline = malloc(sizeof(line) + 1);
```

The above `malloc` will allocate memory with the `size of pointer` + 1.

*Hence when you access `newline` out of bound, you will get **undefined behavior**.*

`newline[j++] = line[i];`

Try as below instead.

```
char * newline = malloc(strlen(line) + 1);
```

Comment: Thank you kiran. But after changed like this, it seems that noting changs in output, it just print one line hello world in stdout, and noting in add1.txt.

Comment: @rubic For me it is working perfectly. Did you miss something?

Comment: Oh i got it, i did miss something. Thank you kiran again.